# Валидация в Laravel. Почему контроллер?

Tags: laravel, laravel5

Почему в Laravel из коробки валидация подразумевается в контроллере, а не в модели?

[В документации](http://laravel.su/docs/5.0/validation#controller-validation) сказано, что Базовый контроллер `App\Http\Controllers\Controller` включает в себя трейт `ValidatesRequests`, который уже содержит методы для валидации.

Вопрос почему не базовый класс модели сразу содержит методы валидации?

Ведь столько сказано о тонких контроллерах толстых моделях. 
Вот например ответ пользователя @HaruAtari с Тостера:

Я считаю, что "толстая модель, тонкий контроллер" - это самый подходящий вариант.
Вся логика приложения должна содержаться в моделях. Модель - это не просто сущности из бд, это еще и инкапсулированая логика ее обработки. А контроллер должен говорить модели, что делать и рендерить вьюхи.

Например этот кусок кода неправильный:

```
class MyController
{
    public function myAction()
    {
        $user = new User();
        $user->load($_POST);
        if ($user->valiadate()) {
            $user->saveToDatabase();
        } else {
            throw new Exception("...");
        }
    }
}
```

Неправильный потому что контроллер знает, как модель сохраняет данные. Что сначала идет валидация, а потом сохранение в бд. И если вы потом решите не проводить валидацию, или добавить еще один проверяющий метод (например), то вам придется делать это везде.

Правильно быдет так: в модели определеить метод, содержащий логику:

```
class User
{
    public static function create(array $data)
    {
        $record= new static;
        $record->load($data);
        if($record->validate()){
            $record->saveToDatabase();
        } else {
            throw new Exception("...");
        }

        return $record;
    }
}
```

А в контроллере просто дергать его и передавать туда данные:

```
class MyController
{
    public function myAction()
    {
        $user = User::create($_POST);
    }
}
```

Таким образом все логика работы модели (в том числе валидация) инкапсулирована снутри класса, и другие классы не знают, как это происходит.

Такой подход облегчает сопровождение кода а так же облегчает написание тестов.

Comment: Не знаком с Laravel, но модель это смысловое ядро приложения. Поэтому существует такая позиция (не одобряю и не порицаю), что валидацию стоит вынести в контроллеры, а обратный процесс (форматирование, например, в виде JSON) - в шаблоны. То есть, модель априори работает только с правильными входными данными и выдает только данные в форме, не зависящей от того, как они будут дальше отображаться. С другой стороны говорят, что "валидного" ID из запроса может вообще не оказаться в таблице БД, то есть он не валидный. И обработать эту ситуацию может только модель.

Comment: Представь, у тебя контроллер, в нем методы store и update например. Тебе придется в модель передать обьект Request и в случае ошибки модель будет отдавать массив ошибок. Может ещ' и редирект из модели делать? Тогда зачем контроллер?

Comment: Jonny не совсем так. Тогда зачем контроллер? Контроллер как раз нужен для обработки и подготовки объекта Request, в нашем случае. Для передачи параметров в модель и для возврата представления. Все. В модель мы должны передать не объект Request , а массив например $data = $request->all() или например $data = $request->except('_token'); - подготовленный вариант. В случае ошибок валидации не нужно передавать массив ошибок, достаточно просто остановить скрипт в модели и передать управление контроллеру, и вернуть вид, без массива ошибок.  Массив $errors будет доступен и будет хранить ошибки.

Comment: Связанные: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/873600/256824

Answer (score 3):

Конкретно в Laravel модель представляет из себя сущность, например какую-либо таблицу из БД, валидация же относится к бизнес-логике и вынесена соответственно в контроллер

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю на счет того времени, когда задавался вопрос, но на таекщий момент валидацию правильнее всего выносить в Request классы. Это позволяет не дублировать код и не хранить логику валидации ни в контроллерах ни в моделях.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#form-request-validation