# Куда вы выносите бизнес-логику из контроллера в Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel5

Раньше всегда загромождал свои контроллеры лишним кодом. Сейчас как минимум что касается моделей, лежит там. Но вот куда и как вынести остальную бизнес-логику? Где вы создаете пользовательские директории для своих классов и как их именуете? Уже час гуглю, не могу найти вменяемой информации на эту тему.

Comment: Вот хорошая статья https://habr.com/company/jugru/blog/419179/. Вот для php https://elisdn.ru/blog/105/services-and-controllers

Answer (score 0):

- Валидацию можно выносить в [Form Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#form-request-validation).
- Можно использовать
  трейты.
- Можно использовать свои классы, где угодно их хранить, делать автозагрузку через композер или регистрировать через [ServiceContainer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/container).

Если у Вас в контроллере какую-то логику можно вынести в класс, то Вы можете вынести и зарегистрировать этот класс как singelton ([как тут в примерах](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/providers#the-register-method)), например. Можно использовать контракты и фасады для удобства. Главное до конца понять что такое сервис контейнер и сервис провайдер. Если не понимаете как выносить какую-то логику в классы, то должны быть статьи и тут надо хорошо понимать ООП.